# Flutter issue - iOS platform not able to load the video from S3 (PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null))

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, ios-camera

I am trying to play a video from S3 storage on Iphone X (14.71 iOS version) but I receive the following error:

```
2021-10-10 00:43:02.134221+0200 Runner[2045:114048] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)
```

The video is successfully uploaded on S3 but I have no luck running it based on the URL.

URL seems to be correct as the issue is not seen on Android devices.

I've also tried the https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4 video which seems to be working on iOS.

For some reason only the S3 uploaded videos captured by my phone cannot be played.

Below is the video_player version in pubspec.yaml:
`video_player: 0.2.5`

Flutter version: `2.6.0-11.0.pre`

Flutter channel: `dev channel`